# ObservableCollection of generic ViewModel class

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, generics, observablecollection

I'm creating *MVVM* application and in *Model* section I have simple base abstract class **Animal** and class **Dog** which derives from it:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*ViewModel* section containts UI-friendly **VM** classes of them:

```
public abstract class AnimalVM<T> : ViewModelBase where T : Animal
{
    protected readonly T animal;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return animal.Age; }
        set
        {
            animal.Age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    protected AnimalVM(T animal)
    {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
}

public class DogVM : AnimalVM<Dog>
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return animal.Name; }
        set
        {
            animal.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public DogVM(Dog dog) : base(dog) { }
}
```

Suppose I have another **VM** class which contains `ObservableCollection<AnimalVM>`. The problem is how to create that kind of property which allow me to store there different types of **Animal**? I want to achieve something like this:

```
public class AnimalListVM : ViewModelBase
{
    // here is a problem, because AnimalVM<Animal> isn't compatible with DogVM
    readonly ObservableCollection<AnimalVM<Animal>> animals;
    public ObservableCollection<AnimalVM<Animal>> Animals
    {
        get { return animals; }
    }

    public AnimalListVM(IList<Animal> animals)
    {
        //this.animals = ...            
    }
}
```

I can change `ObservableCollection<AnimalVM<Animal>>` property to `ICollection` property and then create list of **AnimalVM** using some  dictionary *Animal* -> *AnimalVM* wrapper and `Activator.CreateInstance()` - it works but when I try to extend *AnimalListVM* adding another property `SelectedAnimal` which will be binded in sample *View* to e.g. DataGrid control I have another problem with type of that kind of property `SelectedItem`. It can't be of type `AnimalVM<Animal>` because when I have **DogVM** object in my Collection it won't fit with this and throw an exception.

Everything will be clear if only I had non-generic *AnimalVM* but I don't want to copy and paste similar properties in every *DogVM*, *CatVM*, *BirdVM* class derived from *AnimalVM*. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution and of course it's very simple: just create another, non-generic abstract base class for your generic abstract base class and then derive your generic class from that newly created non-generic class. In that case you also must rewrite properties from non-generic class to generic class (to be more specific override them), but you do this only once, so you don't have to copy and paste the same code in every generic derived ViewModel (in our example in every DogVM, CatVM, BirdVM, etc.).